# manual sorting code using up and down arrows

Tags: coldfusion

I had a table where I have a column called as order, right now, the column is having all values as 0 for existing records.

I am displaying that data in frontend and for the order I am actually using arrows to move them up and down by passing the pkid of the row

but I am bit lost how should I build it, to keep things consistent, I will add the pkid value to the order so if there are moved, the ordervalue is always going to be unique.

but i am not sure how should i start it, like what code should be doing this sort manually, its like the arrows will be responsible for moving the record up and down.

nothing related to `jquery`. an example of this type of code will help me figure out how it can work.

those rows whose are not moved will have their values be as `0` set, and once they are moved, they will get value from their `pk` and move the **state up or down depending upon what is pressed.**

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand what you're asking here.

Comment: How many items? Is the list of items static - or can records (theoretically) be added by a different user while the current user is reordering?

Comment: .... though this does sound like an XY problem. :-) If you're not sure how to approach something, better to start by describing *what* you're trying to accomplish, rather than *how* you're trying to accomplish it, because the "how" can sometimes obscure the goal.

Comment: Hi @Ageax Thanks for coming back on his question. The Problem is that i want to swap the records based upon the arrow keys selected, scenario: I have `5` records whose pk keys are `2,3,4,7,10`. and the order column has same values, now on front side, i had up a7 down arrows, if i want to swap the order of 10, it will be `2,3,4,10,7` - so the move is happening like that but the primary keys will not change, only the order of items will change

Comment: i hope i tried making things clear now